# Cast object created in Activator with different types

Tags: .net

in this code I want to receive interface type instead string, and every time cast the object with the given interface. Is it possible?

```
public HashSet<IMenu> GetMenues(string namespaces, ICoordinates menuCoords)
    {
        var menues = new HashSet<IMenu>();
        Type[] types = assembly
            .GetTypes()
            .Where(t => t.Namespace == namespaces)
            .ToArray();
        foreach (var type in types)
        {
            IMenu currentMenu = 
                (IMenu)Activator.CreateInstance(type, new object[] { 
                menuCoords.Row, menuCoords.Col });
                menues.Add(currentMenu);
        }
        var sortedMenues = menues
            .OrderBy(m => m.MenuNumber)
            .ToHashSet();
        return sortedMenues;
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand: where are strings relevant in this code? I must say: `.OrderBy.ToHashSet` isn't going to do anything, because `HashSet` is not sorted

Comment: Please read [ask] and rephrase your question. It's unclear what are you asking.